# How do I provision a WikiPage with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, wiki-pages, provisioning

So far, I'm not able to do anything to provision a WikiPage with Visual Studio.

The most recent avenue was to try calling 
         `SPWeb.Files.Add("dest.aspx", SPTemplateFileType.WikiPage);`

but this fails (regardless of the SPTemplateFileType) with an error that says "The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."This error makes no sense at all.

It shouldn't be this difficult - after all, it seems to me to be a routine thing to do.

If there is a tried and true way to do this (putting the file in a module doesn't work, either), please enlighten me.

TIA
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of Microsoft tech support, this article - [Programmatically Provisioning Wiki Pages with Content and Web Parts in SharePoint 2010](http://sharepointstruggle.blogspot.ca/2011/10/programmatically-provisioning-wiki.html) - gets me much closer to what I wanted in the first place: a way to provision a WikiPage with code and some clear markup.

I'm going to give this a spin in the next few days. Since the above seat-of-the-pants method worked, my situation isn't quite as dire, and I've got a couple of more pressing issues to solve.

Stay Tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most coherent approach I've found so far. Basically, it involves building the page with Sharepoint itself, saving its containing site as a template, importing the template into Visual Studio, and then picking apart the elements files for the magic nuggets:

[Provisioning Wiki Pages in SharePoint 2010 Web Template](http://mnigbor.blogspot.ca/2011/09/provisioning-wiki-pages-in-sharepoint.html)

It works, provided the assembly info contains
   `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]`
as its last line.